# React Native - Connecting to remote WebRTC stream

Tags: react-native, webrtc, video-streaming

We have mobile application that historically has used RTSP streaming to allow a user to watch a live stream, which currently is published via Wowza Streaming Engine. We have had a need to lower stream latency, so have gravitated towards WebRTC to achieve this.

The problem is that there seems to be a lack of documentation, or examples regarding the implementation of a react-native WebRTC viewer which connects to a remote stream.

Does anyone out there have any documentation, or code examples for this kind of implementation?

I do note there is a react-native-webrtc library, however, all examples demonstrate connecting two peers on mobile phones with their video cameras i.e. Like facetime. We are after an example demonstrating someone on a phone connecting to a remote streaming server with a video feed.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If you want a webrtc client to connect to a server you need a server doing webrtc with the proper signaling that fit your need. Webrtc don't care which signaling you use, so you have to choose it or choose a the platform you need.

There are a lot of different media server, or library that support webrtc in server side all having there specific signaling(ex: Freeswitch, Kurento etc), or no signaling (ex: Mediasoup). Few will have a react native version as Media Streaming is not really something in the javascript/UI side but you can do something with the webrtc react-native lib.

Twillio has a lot of supported platform  and could be a good start if you search a ready to use solution.

Comment: Thanks for  the information. We are currently using Wowza streaming engine. Are you indicating that each provider will have their own SDP workflow?

Comment: @DuncanPalmer Yes exactly.